# Using Native WebGL API to assign a video texture to Sphere

Tags: javascript, webgl, opengl-es-2.0

I using webgl programing ,I want to assign a video texture to a sphere,I try many many times, at last I failed,I there any good way to assign a video texture to a sphere using webgl native API without using any other library or framework such as three.js and so on, actually,`gl-matrix` is not incluted. I think,when you want to assign a vedio texture to sphere, you must constructed the sphere's `vetex position`,`texture coordinate` and `vextex index`.and you must update the texture time after time. I do so as above,but it nothing display on the screen, Who can help me,and show me a such demo for me,Thankyou.

Comment: Did you get it working using a still image texture first?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/WebGL/By_example/Video_textures

Comment: yeah，I have already find a way to solve how to mapping a video texture to a shpere with native WebGL API,Thank you all the same,thankyou

Comment: @cughudson could you add your solution as an answer to the question. I can get my video to render on a plane, and I can get a static image to render on a sphere, but can't get the video to render on the sphere.